# Install Reporting Service in SharePoint 2016 is not supports SSRS 2014

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services

we are using SharePoint Server 2016 Farm with 2-WFE,2-Application with Search, and a Database Server (SQL Server 2014). Now I want to Integrate SSRS to SharePoint. Now, MSDN says that SharePoint Server 2016 is supported only SSRS 2016. What should I do now? Is it possible to download and install Reporting Services-SharePoint (2016) separately in Application Server?. But When I tried to install and Configure SSRS 2016 in Single Server Farm (SharePoint 2016 - SQL Server 2014), I have not seen any Content Type with the name of SQL Server Reporting Service Content Types.
 
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what problems if i change min role from application to custom . please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's got worked after Change MinRole from Single-Server to Custom. I thought Change Role was required on multi server farm. But even single-server farm also we need to change MinRole.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the article [Supported combinations of SharePoint and Reporting Services server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server):

- `Combinations that are not list in the following table are not supported`
- `SharePoint 2016 support, including Power view integration, requires the Reporting Services report server and the Reporting Services add-in version of SQL Server 2016 or later.`

That matches my experience: It's not just a question of "being supported or not". Only the listed product-combinations will work.